# Printing only a set value of elements in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I just want to know how to print out Strings in an ArrayList with a given certain value only for the output. For example: I input "Hot", "Cold", "Pressure", "Pain". What method/control statement should I use to make so that the output will only be the words with four letters?

Output:
"Cold"
"Pain"

It only prints "Cold" & "Pain" because they're the only one with four elements.
Will the use of .set be useful?

Comment: Not really, although I suppose it could be used. Wouldn't it make more sense to just iterate over the list and only print out strings that are four letters long?

Comment: Your only real alternative is to iterate over the list, like Dave Newton suggested.  Plan B, if you wanted to go that far, would be to create a parallel index to find "Array index item" by "item length".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you could iterate over the list. If this is a repeated operation, you could use a map to sort the strings by length. See below an example with the 2 solutions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hot", "Cold", "Pressure", "Pain");

    //Solution 1
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.length() == 4) {
            System.out.println(s); //prints Cold and Pain
        }
    }

    //Solution 2
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>> ();
    for (String s : list) {
        int length = s.length();
        if (map.containsKey(length)) {
            map.get(length).add(s);
        } else {
            map.put(length, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s)));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map.get(4)); //prints [Cold, Pain]
    System.out.println(map.get(3)); //prints [Hot]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can add Strings to a map. The key can be the length of the string and the value a list of strings.

`Map<Integer, List<String>>  -> Map<string length, List<String>>`

This one is expected O(1) runtime

- You can keep the strings in a list and traverse them:

```
    List list = ...

    for (String s: list){
        if (s.length()==4){
              print(s);
        }
    }
```

This one has linear runtime

Answer (score 0):

I'd also check for nulls (don't know if they could occur in your situation) to avoid a possible java.lang.NullPointerException:

```java
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hot", "Cold", "Pressure", null, "Pain");

    for (String s : list) {
        if (s != null && s.length() == 4) {
            System.out.println(s); // prints "Cold" and "Pain"
        }
    }
```